# Как вызвать метод getFileExtension в Fragment. getContentResolver(); у меня она высвечивается

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

```
public String getFileExtension (Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `getContentResolver` нужно вызывать от `Context` то есть вот так

```
public String getFileExtension (Context context, Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri)); 
}
```